# Microsoft Store showing completely irrelevant results

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, microsoft-store

## Microsoft Store is showing completely irrelevant search results

A few days ago, I downloaded `Kali Linux` and `Ubuntu` (WSL) on my windows machine. The first installation of Ubuntu didn’t work, so I uninstalled it and went back to Microsoft Store to re-install it. When I searched for `Ubuntu`, I got irrelevant results, like Facebook, Spotify, etc. I tried to search `WSL`, which again didn’t work, and instead of showing wsl distros, it showed me some apps like `WSL Cheat sheet`.

I had to go into installed apps section of Microsoft Store, click on Kali Linux, and in related apps, I had to go to the Ubuntu page and download it from there. Same story for the new `Windows Terminal`.

Does anyone else too have this problem? I haven’t changed a single setting of the `Microsoft Store`.

Thank You! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This also happened to be the case with me, both with WSL distros and the new terminal, +1. However at that time I just discarded as a wierd anomaly and went to the online version : [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/windows) and searched there. Then it promted me to open the windows store(the app) and I installed just like that. I know It isn't a solution, but it can surely help you for the time, While I eagerly wait for someone to answer this question.